# how to identify a button in a group of loop generated buttons?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans, jbutton

I have a group of loop generated buttons made with this code

```
this.panelCuerpo.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,5));
    for(int i = 1; i<=20; i++){
        final JToggleButton b = new JToggleButton(new ImageIcon("/images/available.png"));            
        panelCuerpo.add(b);

        b.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/available1.png")));
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){                    
                if(b.isSelected()){
                    b.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/busy1.png")));
                    cantidadBoletas++;                        
                }else{
                    b.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/available1.png")));
                    cantidadBoletas--;
                }
                System.out.println(cantidadBoletas);
            } 
        });
    }
```

The problem here is that I can't use setText() to compare later cause there's no property to hide that text. How can I compare it later?

PS. Each button has a consecutive number, it's easy to assign that number. The real problem lies in where to put it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could:

- Use the `Action` API, which lets you trigger the `selected` state of the associated button.  This allows you to de-couple the button from the underlying "action" it should take.  Take a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)[How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details
- Use the `actionCommand` property of the `JButton`.  This allows you to have some kind of "identifier" associated with the button which is independent of the text
- Use an array or `List` to maintain a reference to the buttons

Comment: I decided to use the second option, that was what I was looking for but I can't save the consecutive number. It'll always be "1 - 0" (the 1 is right, the 0 isn't. Each button is supposed to have its own number). Any idea?

Comment: Use "i" from the loop?

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i<=19; i++){
            final JToggleButton b = new JToggleButton(new ImageIcon("/images/available.png"));            
            panelCuerpo.add(b);
            
            b.setActionCommand(String.valueOf(1+i));
            b.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/available1.png")));
            b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {`

It doesn't take it, always is 0

Comment: Make user you are using ActionEvent#getActionCommand and not the reference of b

Comment: That was the problem, I was using the b reference. "evt" (the parameter from the actionPerformed() was the correct way).

Answer (score 2):

You can maintain a `List<JToggleButton>` of `JToggleButton` and fetch element later by the `index`. Apart from that instead of adding `ActionListener` in loop you can implement `ActionListener` which can be used for all buttons and you just need to write `b.addActionListener(this);` in loop.

*NOTE* : better to start from `i = 0` instead of `1`